# Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Wrong number of segments when i use the jwt decode function in php

Tags: php, flutter, jwt

I'm new to JWT and doing an exercise to understand it better.
I am trying to send the token from the client side using flutter via the header and in php I am trying to use the decode function.
The problem is that I get the error: "Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Wrong number of segments " in the localhost php pg without sending anything to it, without doing anything.

If I show the variable $resultado2 in the array it returns null, without doing anything from the client side.

I think the error "Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Wrong number of segments" is taken as null in the decode function in the variable $resultado2

the problem is in the decode method.

How could I solve that problem?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```php
//php code
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$headertoken = $headers['authorization'];

$resultado = str_replace("Bearer","",$headertoken); 
$resultado2 = substr($resultado,1); 

$decoded = JWT::decode($resultado2,new Key($key,'HS256'));

$array = array(
        'estado' => 'ok-validado',
        'heade' => $headertoken, 
        'uss' => $resultado2,
    );
    
    echo json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE |  JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

```dart
// flutter code
Map<String, String> header = {

        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
      };

      var Url= Uri.parse("http://....");
      var response = await http.post(Url,
          body:{
            'contra' : Contras,
            'corr' : Corr,

          },
        headers: header
      ).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 90)) ;
  var data = json.decode(response.body);
 if(data['estado'] == "ok-validado"){  
print("correct");
}else{print("incorrect");}`
```

how to solve my problem

Comment: Have you tried matching the header casing? `$headers['Authorization']`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php#124236

Comment: yes, it works for me with "authorization"